# Cannot read csv in zipfile in python

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have a folder with several zipfiles in it:

```
A.ZIP, B.ZIP, C.ZIP
```

they are all protected with the same password and all have one file in it, i try to read all the zipfiles to get one dataframe out of it:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
password = b'lordofrings' # Set password
zipfiles = glob.glob(r"C:\..\*.ZIP") # Get list of zip files
zipfiles
zfs = [(zipfile.ZipFile(f), f.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0] + '.csv') for f in zipfiles]

# Get ZipFile object and csv file name for each zip file
dfs = [pd.read_csv(zf.open(filename, 'r', password), header=None, sep=';') for zf, filename in zfs]
```

But somehow the last row occurs an error:

> KeyError: "There is no item named 'A.csv' in
>   the archive"

What is my error?

The previous steps lead to:

```
zfs
[(<zipfile.ZipFile filename='C:\\...\\A.ZIP' mode='r'>,
  'A.csv'), 
 (<zipfile.ZipFile filename='C:\\...\\D.ZIP' mode='r'>,
  'D.csv')]
```

Comment: you can read zipped files directly in pandas `pd.read_csv('A.zip', compression='zip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')`

Comment: even when they are password protected?

Comment: ah yes, silly me missed that, best bet is to use a context manager give me a mo.

Comment: or easier for me I will remove that password...

Comment: Are there any members in the archive with an extension that could be different from `.csv`?

Comment: no, in every zipfile is one csv file

Comment: What is the result of `[f, zipfile.Zipfile(f).namelist() for f in zipfiles]`?

Comment: what do you mean?